# Check if user credentials match, without authenticating

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

Using the FOSUserbundle, I want to achieve the following:

1) User submits a POST with "username" and "password" parameters. Password is in plaintext.

2) In a controller, I parse the parameters as usual:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/token",name="api_token")
 */
public function tokenAction(Request $request) {

    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    // ...
}
```

3) Finally, if the credentials match, I return something.

Note that I want to do this WITHOUT modifying the session, i.e. without actually authenticating the user and setting a token. I only want to check if the credentials match.

**UPDATE**

The accepted answer works, but only under the assumption that you have an active session. If you want to solve the case where you simply expose a REST layer or the like (which was my usecase), you can do the following, assuming your usernames are unique:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/token",name="api_token", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function getTokenAction(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
                 ->getRepository('YourUserClass')
                 ->findOneBy(["username" => $username]);

    $encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);

    $isValidPassword = $encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(),
                                                 $password,
                                                 $user->getSalt());

    if ($isValidPassword) {
        // Handle success
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#using-password-encoders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an authentication service to do this, writing all code in controller is not a best practice. Anyway, to your answer, you can use this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/token",name="api_token")
 */
public function tokenAction(Request $request) {

    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    // fetch your user using user name
    $user = ...

   //If your controller is extended from Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
   $encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
   //If you are extending from other ContainerAware Controller you may have to do 
   //$this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user)

   //Check your user
    $isValidPassword = $encoder->isPasswordValid(
            $user->getPassword(),
            $password,
            $user->getSalt()
    );

    if ($isValidPassword) {
       //.... do your valid stuff
    }else{
       //... Do your in valid stuff
    }
}
```